# How can i bundle react app that needs jquery ajax call

Tags: reactjs, gulp, ecmascript-6, browserify, babeljs

I am developing a react app using ecma6 standard. now i am creating a bundle to be used in browser using the gulpfile.js below :

```js
var gulp = require('gulp');
var browserify = require('browserify');
var babelify = require('babelify');
var source = require('vinyl-source-stream');
var glob = require('glob');

gulp.task('build', function () {

  browserify({
    entries: 'index.jsx',
    extensions: ['.jsx'],
    debug: true
  })
  .transform(babelify)
  .bundle()
  .pipe(source('bundle.js'))
  .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});
 
gulp.task('default', ['build']);
```

Now I have one of the react component that uses jQuery ajax calls, something like this :

```js
 componentDidMount() {
    $.ajax({
      url: this.props.url,
      dataType: 'json',
      cache: false,
      success: function(data) {
        this.setState({data: data});
      }.bind(this),
      error: function(xhr, status, err) {
        console.error(this.props.url, status, err.toString());
      }.bind(this)
    });
  }
```

How can i modify my gulp file so that the jquery codes can be included in the react code?

Comment: If you only want jquery for ajax you might not need jquery: http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/. You can, for example, use superagent or axios. You can read more about them in this article from sitepoint: http://www.sitepoint.com/comparison-javascript-http-libraries/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to use jQuery in my code by following the steps below :

1) install jquery package using the command

**npm install jquery**

2)import the package in the component you want to use jQuery with statement

**import $ from 'jquery';**